# Public facing Flask Webserver possible to get hacked?

Tags: python, flask, server, webserver

I am running a public-facing Flask webserver and encountered GET requests from random IPs. To what extent are hackers able to access my files? Is it just limited to the webserver folder? or can they access files beyond the webserver and on the machine itself? Below are some of the GET requests recieved:

```
"GET /mysqladmin/index.php?lang=en HTTP/1.1" 404 -
"GET /mysql/pMA/index.php?lang=en HTTP/1.1" 404 -
"GET /phpMyAdmin-5/index.php?lang=en HTTP/1.1" 404 -
"GET /phpMyAdmin-5/index.php?lang=en HTTP/1.1" 404 -
"GET /phpmyadmin_/index.php?lang=en HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

Comment: requests show that it checks if you use [phpMyAdmin](https://www.phpmyadmin.net/) or other popular tools and frameworks (like `WordPress`) and it checks if they still have old bugs which may give access to all settings and data in these tools.`Flask` rather is not target in these attacks but you still may use arguments from url to execute code which may gives some information. ie. if you create manually SQL query using parameters from url then they still can send something like `or 1=1; INSERT ....` to try to add some value to database (i.e. admin with own password).

Comment: there are tools which can check if your server has some bugs which hackers could uses https://pentest-tools.com/website-vulnerability-scanning/website-scanner, `OWASP`. On https://nmap.org you can find link to list of TOP popular tools for security and there are also [web scanners](https://sectools.org/tag/web-scanners/). For more you can also ask on other Stackoverflow's portal [Information Security](https://security.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Flask is enough secure but it's clear you are facing a suspicious activity and intrusion attempts, so you need an other level of security, i would suggest you installing `fail2ban` to black-list suspecious IP addresses after a predefined number of failures from a host.

refer to

- https://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page

some tutorials:

- https://linuxize.com/post/install-configure-fail2ban-on-ubuntu-20-04/
- https://www.a2hosting.com/kb/security/hardening-a-server-with-fail2ban